# Relation has a, inheritance and casting

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Lets suppose I have the following classes:

```
abstract class AbstractEngine{...}
abstract class AbstractTransmission {...}
abstract class AbstractCar {
   private AbstractEngine engine;
   private AbstractTransmission transmission;
   //setters and getters 
  ...
}

class ConcreteEngine extends AbstractEngine{...}
class ConcreteTransmission extends AbstractTransmission{...}
class ConcreteCar extends AbstractCar {
   public void move() {
      ConcreteEngine engine = (ConcreteEngine)getEngine();
      ConcreteTransmission transmission = (ConcreteTransmission) getTransmission();
      ....
   }
}
```

As you see in ConcreteCar we will have a lot of casting for working with concrete details. It seems to me that I am doing something wrong here. Can I anyhow avoid so many casting using `has a` relation and inheritance?

Comment: Why do you have to cast to concrete classes, aren't the methods declared in the abstract classes enough to work with, without knowing their exact implementation ?

Comment: @Berger Concrete details have a lot of additional features. And every concrete car differs from other cars by its details and their (own) features.

Comment: You can override the getter methods in the `Concrete` class and further 'concrete' the return type. This way you have to do the casting only once, but you can't avoid it.

Comment: This is a good example for answering "Abstract class vs Interface, when to use which?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, such *downcasts* are most often a symptom of a bad design.

In your case - it seems that your abstractions are not good enough.

In other word: your **base** (abstract) classes should provide all the *behavior that one needs to deal with the corresponding object.

Meaning: to a user of `AbstractEngine` it should absolutely *not* matter what implementation is behind that object. Therefore: look into the **interface** that your abstract classes are offering; and rework them in a way that allows you to do the **necessary** things *without* instanceof checks and downcasts.

It might also be worthwhile to look into "splitting" your functionality into a set of **interfaces**; allowing you for more "fine granular" slicing of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a typical example for the usage of generics. You do not need type casting if you modify your code like this:

```
abstract class AbstractEngine{};
abstract class AbstractTransmission {};
abstract class  AbstractCar<E extends AbstractEngine, T extends AbstractTransmission> {
    private E engine;
    private T transmission;
    public E getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
    public T getTransmission() {
        return transmission;
    }
}

class ConcreteEngine extends AbstractEngine{};
class ConcreteTransmission extends AbstractTransmission{};
class ConcreteCar extends AbstractCar<ConcreteEngine, ConcreteTransmission> {
   public void move() {
      ConcreteEngine engine = getEngine();
      ConcreteTransmission transmission = getTransmission();
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach; didn't think about using generics here.

Answer (score -1):

You should make use of Polymorphism. Try

AbstractEngine engine = getEngine()

This will compile because ConcreteEngine is-a AbstractEngine. Also this is better OOP practice because this way your program will be more flexible to future changes.

Comment: His method is **returning** an abstract type. His question is: how to avoid the **downcast** in order to do the required concrete things. Your answer doesn't help at all.